# Puppy precise - sudo command not found on bootable CD

Tags: linux, bash, bootable

I downloaded the `.iso` file and burned it to a rewritable CD. But when trying to install a PHP server (xampp) from the command line, as instructed in http://wikihow.com/Install-XAMPP-on-Linux my puppy says that the sudo command isn't found.
 This might be a silly question but I'm new to bash and Linux in general.

What should I do? Is there maybe another command for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Puppy Linux does not require `sudo` because "[Puppy Linux typically is a single user OS. The single user is run as the root account with full privileges.](http://puppylinux.org/wikka/spot)" So execute the command without `sudo`. However, you might require that if you are using `fido` (read the page pointed above).